# Where to save scraped images?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, web-scraping

I'm building a Ruby on Rails app that scrapes the images off a website. What is the best location to save this images to?

Edit:
To be clear, I know the file system is the best type of storage, but where on the file system? I suppose I have to stay in the RoR app directory, but which folder is best suitable for this? `public`?

Comment: The file system, I would imagine.  Without more information, it's difficult to be more specific.

Comment: Yes ofcourse the file system, but where exactly. RoR apps have a specific structure, but I don't know what directory is best suitable for this.

Comment: Typical solution: Somewhere under `public`. See, for instance: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby-on-rails/rails-file-uploading.htm

Comment: Acting as the intellectual-property police and providing a gentle tap on the shoulder as a reminder: You do have permission to scrape the images and serve them right? Scraping them implies you do not, which could lead to your host/site being banned, or worse, a lawsuit. Check to be sure you are within the terms-of-service for the site you are accessing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On your file server (static Apache server), on your app server (save some where locally in the disk and serve via the app server) or on [Amazon S3](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/)

But I would suggest not to store in Database. (Some people think it's alright. So, I would be limited to suggestion)

---

in ROR, under `<app_name>/public/images` [see here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby-on-rails/rails-file-uploading.htm) -- but the data will be public. If you are worried about privacy, probably this is not right.

If you are concerned about privacy, see the options discussed  here [How to store private pictures and videos in Ruby on Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2752497/how-to-store-private-pictures-and-videos-in-ruby-on-rails) But as a sughestion: serving files from app-server may be painful in high traffic conditions and my experience is it better off-loaded to a  file server or a cloud like S3.

Comment: Expanding on "not to store in Database" answer: Files are for the filesystem. Databases are not designed for files. Just don't do that, please.

Comment: If I would like the data to be private, then what location do you recommend?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2752497/how-to-store-private-pictures-and-videos-in-ruby-on-rails you can see various options suggested here. Please note that service file from your app-server is a burden in high traffic. Better off load it to cloud.

Answer (score 0):

It's not hard to write and/or create a server that is only serving images from a file store outside your website's directory structure. A simple rewrite of the URL can provide your code with the info it needs to the actual file location, which it then outputs to the browser.

An alternate is to have the image's URL mapped to the image's directory path in a database, then do a lookup. Make the URL field an indexed lookup and it will be very fast.

I wrote an image server in Ruby a couple years ago along those lines and it was a pretty simple task.