# Rails - Setting routes for custom paperclip url's

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes, paperclip

I've set a custom paperclip path and url as follows:

```
path: ":rails_root/storage/:rails_env/photos/:id/:style/:basename.:extension",
url: "/storage/:rails_env/photos/:id/:style/:basename.:extension"
```

But now I need to work out how to create a route so that I can access every photo for every instance of the model with this attachment with the url (e.g.):

```
http://0.0.0.0:3000/storage/development/photos/1/original/_MG_7918.JPG
```

Everything I've tried so far has ended with the same error:

```
No route matches [GET] "/storage/development/photos/1/original/_MG_7918.JPG"
```

Can someone help me out as to what structure my routes are going to need to take to get access to files in this directory structure?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom controller for attachments. You'll need to create a controller method and route:

```
# config/routes.rb
match "/storage/*path" => "attachments#show"

#app/controllers/attachments_controller.rb
class AttachmentsController
  def show
    # ...
  end
end
```

You can take a look to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2752497/how-to-store-private-pictures-and-videos-in-ruby-on-rails/2752585#2752585), notice my comment to make it efficient.

Another solution is to create a symlink from `public` dir to the `storage` dir.